# Magento 2 Can't get the sales rules conditions in my ui form at edit time Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, shopping-cart-price-rules, backend, ui-form

I create custom module for add rule condition in custom module but not get condition data on edit time here i share my files

> vendor_module_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="conditions_fieldset">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <container name="conditions_serialized_container" >
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <htmlContent name="html_content">
                        <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Message\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
                    </htmlContent>
                </container>
            </fieldset>
```

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Message\Edit\Tab\Conditions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Message\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

class Conditions extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $rendererFieldset;

    protected $conditions;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RuleFactory $labelFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->conditions = $conditions;
        $this->labelFactory = $labelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __("Conditions");
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __("Conditions");
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry("current_label");
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    protected function addTabToForm(
        $model,
        $fieldsetId = "conditions_fieldset",
        $formName = "message_form"
    ) {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
            $model = $this->labelFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            "msg/message/newConditionHtml/form/conditions_fieldset"
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix("rule_");
        $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset
            ->setTemplate("Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml")
            ->setNewChildUrl($newChildUrl);

        $fieldset = $form
            ->addFieldset($fieldsetId, [
                "legend" => __(
                    "Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)."
                ),
            ])
            ->setRenderer($renderer);
        $fieldset
            ->addField("conditions", "text", [
                "name" => "conditions",
                "label" => __("Conditions"),
                "title" => __("Conditions"),
                "required" => true,
                "data-form-part" => $formName,
            ])
            ->setRule($model)
            ->setRenderer($this->conditions);

        $form->setValues($model->getData());

        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    private function setConditionFormName(
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions,
        $formName
    ) {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if (
            $conditions->getConditions() &&
            is_array($conditions->getConditions())
        ) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Message\NewConditionHtml.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Message;

class NewConditionHtml extends \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Message\Rule
{
    /**
     * New condition html action
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $labelFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\RuleFactory');
        $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
        $type = $typeArr[0];
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
            $type
        )->setId(
            $id
        )->setType(
            $type
        )->setRule(
            $labelFactory->create()
        )->setPrefix(
            'conditions'
        );

        if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
            $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
        }

        if ($model instanceof \Vendor\Module\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition) {
            $model->setFormName('message_form')->setJsFormObject('conditions_fieldset');
            $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Message\Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Message;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;
use Vendor\Module\Model\MessageFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /*
     * @var Message
     */
    protected $messageModel;
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $adminsession;
    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param Message           $messageModel
     * @param Session        $adminsession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        MessageFactory $messageModel,
        Session $adminsession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->messageModel = $messageModel;
        $this->adminsession = $adminsession;
    }
    /**
     * Save message record action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        

        
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $model = $this->messageModel->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        
        $customerGroup = implode(',',$data['customer_group']);
        $data['customer_group'] = $customerGroup;

        $website = implode(',',$data['website']);
        $data['website'] = $website;
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data);






        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $data['updated_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                
                $model->load($id);
            }


            if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
                $data['conditions'] = json_encode($data['rule']['conditions']);
            }
            
            unset($data['rule']);
            // print_r($data['conditions']);
            // exit;
                
            $model->setData($data);
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
                $this->adminsession->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back') == 'add') {
                        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/add');
                    } else {
                        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                    }
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            }
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
    
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
 
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Message\CollectionFactory;
 
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    private $loadedData;
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $messageCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $messageCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $messageCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $blog) {
            
            $this->loadedData[$blog->getId()] = $blog->getData();
            $this->loadedData['conditions_fieldset'] = $blog->getData('conditions_fieldset');

        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that I just change my db_schema.xml file

the all code is correct just need to change the condition field name from "conditions" to "conditions_serialized"

than it's works fine

```
<column xsi:type="text" name="conditions_serialized" nullable="true" comment="Rule"/>
```